# TYPO3 9.5 Extbase plugin cache implementation

Tags: caching, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I am trying to get a cache working in my plugin.
In ext_localconf.php

```
if (!is_array($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension'])) {
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension'] = [];}

if (!isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension']['frontend'])) {
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension']['frontend'] = 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Frontend\\StringFrontend';}

if (!isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension']['options'])) {
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension']['options'] = ['defaultLifetime' => 0];}

if (!isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension']['groups'])) {
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['myextension']['groups'] = ['pages'];}
```

In my controller action :

```
$cacheIdentifier = 'topic' . $topic->getUid();
$cache = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(CacheManager::class)->getCache('myextension');

$result = unserialize($cache->get($cacheIdentifier));

if ($result !== false ) {
    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($result);
} else {
    $result = $this->postRepository->findByTopic($topic->getUid(), $page, $itemsPerPage);
    $cache->set($cacheIdentifier, serialize($result), ['tag1', 'tag2']);
    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($result);
}
```

The first time the page with the action gets loaded all is ok and the entry has been made in de database (cf_myextension and cf_myextension_tags}.

But the 2nd time the cache gets loaded and I get an error. Even `DebuggerUtility::var_dump($result);` does not work:

```
Call to a member function map() on null    
in ../typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/QueryResult.php line 96

*/
protected function initialize()
{
    if (!is_array($this->queryResult)) {
        $this->queryResult = $this->dataMapper->map($this->query->getType(), $this->persistenceManager->getObjectDataByQuery($this->query));
    }
}

/**
```

A normal var_dump works and spits out the cache entry. What is the problem? Do I forget something? Can't a QueryResult together with some other variables not be stored as an array in the cache? I also tried VariableFrontend cache, which produced the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The E-tools GUI application indents and pretty formats HTML, JavaScript, JSON and SQL. To install the e-tools snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install e-tools
```